# Can I type hint my object as a TypedDict?

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

I have a an object that looks and behaves similar to a dictionary that I have minimal control over, but I would like to add precise typing to function that receives it, maybe type hinted in a similar way to `TypedDict`? Is this possible?

The object that behaves like a dictionary is implemented something like this

```
class MyDictImplementation:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.values[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.values[item]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.values.__repr__()})'
```

This would be initiated with

```
foo = MyDictImplementation({'project': MyDictImplementation({'states': MyDictImplementation({0: MyDictImplementation({'enabled': True, 'group': 'Meta'})})})})
```

Which would be this as a dictionary

```
foo = {'project': {"states": {0: {"enabled": True, "group": 'Meta'}}}}
```

To type hint this dictionary I could create a chain of `TypedDict` and set that as the functions type hint.

```
class StatusState(typing.TypedDict):
    enabled: bool
    group: str


class States(typing.TypedDict):
    states: typing.Dict[int, StatusState]


class Project(typing.TypedDict):
    project: States


def typing_test(input_: Project):
    pass

foo: Project = {'project': {"states": {0: {"enabled": True, "group": 'Meta'}}}}

typing_test(foo)  # Works!
```

I would like to give `typing_test` a `MyDictImplementation` object instead and be properly type hinted. Is this possible?

```
foo = MyDictImplementation({'project': MyDictImplementation({'states': MyDictImplementation({0: MyDictImplementation({'enabled': True, 'group': 'Meta'})})})})

typing_test(foo)
```

---

Full test/example for your convenience

```
class StatusState(typing.TypedDict):
    enabled: bool
    group: str


class States(typing.TypedDict):
    states: typing.Dict[int, StatusState]


class Project(typing.TypedDict):
    project: States


class MyDictImplementation:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.values[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.values[item]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.values.__repr__()})'


def typing_test(input_: Project):
    pass

foo: Project = {'project': {"states": {0: {"enabled": True, "group": 'Meta'}}}}
bar = MyDictImplementation({'project': MyDictImplementation({'states': MyDictImplementation({0: MyDictImplementation({'enabled': True, 'group': 'Meta'})})})})

typing_test(foo)  # This is fine
typing_test(bar)  # This isn't
```

Comment: As far as I know, `TypedDict` only works for values of type `dict`, not values of arbitrary mapping classes.